# how to stop the Plsql procedure block

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I wants to stop the plsql procedure if any exception happens on calling any sub procedure.

For below example ,

I wants to stop the entire process if first_sub_proc gives any exception. I had used "return" statement here. But there is no use.  Always,If any thing happens on first_sub_proc, then execute the exception block of first_sub_procdure. Hence after, it will go back to main function and  start processing the second_sub_proc.

any suggestion ?

```
create or replace 
package body testing_pk as

procedure first_sub_proc is 
  begin 
    dbms_output.put_line('Entering the first sub');
    execute immediate 'truncate table not_present';

  Exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('first sub  procedure exception ');
     -- *****Need to stop the entire process here ****
end;

procedure second_proc is 
  begin 
    dbms_output.put_line('Entering the Second sub');
    execute immediate 'truncate table not_present';
  Exception when others then
     dbms_output.put_line('second sub procedure exception ');
end;


procedure main_proc is 
   begin
     dbms_output.put_line('Entering main ');
     first_sub_proc();  
     second_proc();    

   Exception when others then
     dbms_output.put_line('Main procedure exception ');
 end;
```

Comment: If you put a RAISE statement at the *****Need to stop the entire process here **** position, the code will raise the error to the calling main_proc.
This will then enter the main_proc exception handler.

You can also raise user defined errors using PRAGMA_INIT and handle these exceptions seperate to your WHEN OTHERS.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#BABGIIBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `return` try with `raise` or `raise_application_error(-20800, 'The dreaded thing has happened');`.

Of course, what exactly you understand under *the program should stop* is a bit undefined.